# InApp Messaging Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

It gives me Unable to merge dex error. If i comment dependency of InApp Messaging then it works fine.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
>
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

Let me know if any solution available for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.firebasedatabasedemo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

It's solved by changing gradle dependency to 3.1.4 version & by integrating multidex.

Answer (score 1):

Goto: **ProjectFolder->.idea->libraries->Delete All**

Then **Build->Project->Rebuild**

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` dependencies . May be there are some conflicts in your gradle files.